# Sobre la libreria pyjstat para json

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando leer un json con pyjstat pero me da un error:

> KeyError: 'dimension'

Este es el código:

```
from pyjstat import pyjstat

EXAMPLE_URL ='http://www.cso.ie/StatbankServices/StatbankServices.svc/jsonservice/responseinstance/AQA04'
query = [{'Type of Crop': 'Total wheat'}, {'Year': '2008'}, {'Statistic': 'AQA04C2'}]
dataset = pyjstat.Dataset.read(EXAMPLE_URL)
print(dataset.get_value(query))
```

No conozco mucho la librería, pero por lo que he visto busca un campo `['dimension']['id']` pero el json si lo tiene y no se porque da error... ¿Alguien lo entiende?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que el formato del JSON de la URL que aportas no es correcto para esta librería. No es capaz de leer la clave "dimension" y eso es porque requiere del nivel superior. Si eliminas el nivel "dataset" si te lee esa clave "dimension" pero aún así sigue dando problemas.

Según los creadores funciona con Python 3.4
También indican que requieren jstat 2.0 ya que la 1.3 está desfasada, de hecho el ejemplo que ponen es con jstat 2.0

Comment: Muchas gracias... me aclara mucho, voy a ver si encuentro mas informacion.